disable browser back button in angular 8
I want to disable browser back button on specific condition, after implementing several snippets
like History,popstate etc
scenario 1: its making the code not able to use back button for anything disregarding the condition.
scenario 2: once you click back button twice its going back to browsers home page not able to know whats happening
window.addEventListener("popstate", (e) => {
  const es = 'D'
  if (es == "D") {
    e.preventDefault();

    var currentLocation = window.location.pathname;
    window.history.pushState(
      {},
      "",
      `${currentLocation}/index/watchlist/home`
    );
  } else {

Need: Need to disable the back button conditionally but if the condition is false it should work

You should not be able to do this. You can display a warning that unsaved data will be lost if you have data on the page.

Personally any attempts to disable or otherwise intercept/effect my use of the browser back button gets one response: close the browser window and never visit that site again.  Ever.

please provide some better solutions
